# Get this notification when I want to install files via XDM

Tags: 20.04

How to fix :

XDM Browser Monitor
Browser monitoring is disabled

Please make sure XDM is runnning and you have latest version of XDM installed, This addon is compatible with XDM 7.0 or higher

Comment: What is XDM? How did you installed it? What browser is used?

Comment: XDM (Xtreme Download Manager) is a software used to download files, its function is the same as IDM (Internet Download Manager) on Windows, I learned to install it via the command line.

I use the Chrome browser.

Comment: Please write the steps of XDM installation. Provide its version.

Comment: https://sourcedigit.com/24914-how-to-install-xtreme-download-manager-xdm-on-ubuntu-linux/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reinstall newer version of XDM (Xtreme Download Manager) from its site - http://xdman.sourceforge.net .

Open terminal and type:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://github.com/subhra74/xdm/releases/download/7.2.11/xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
tar -xf xdm-setup-7.2.11.tar.xz
sudo ./install.sh
```

And then install browser AddOn on any supported browser.

Comment: Hi, N0bert..

Thank you very much for the help, it works for me.

Comment: Great, so you can accept my answer by clicking on check-mark on the left-side of it.

Comment: Yeap.. Its donee..